# $x^{10}+x^{11}+\dots+x^{20}$ divided by $x^3+x$. Remainder?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, roots

Question:

> If $x^{10}+x^{11}+\dots+x^{20}$ is divided by $x^3+x$, then what is the remainder?
> Options: (A) $x\qquad\quad$ (B)$-x\qquad\quad$ (C)$x^2\qquad\quad$ (D)$-x^2$

In these types of questions generally I follow the following approach:

> Since divisor is cubic so the remainder must be a constant/linear/quadratic expression.
> $\Rightarrow F(x)=(x^3+x)Q(x)+ax^2+bx+c$
> For $x=0$, we get $c=0$

But since $x^3+x$ has no other roots so I can't find $a$ and $b$.
Please help.

Answer:

> Option (B)

Comment: $x^3+x$ has three roots, even if two of them are complex.

Comment: Spoilers should not be in questions

Comment: @lulu the complex roots don't seem helpful to me here

Comment: Of course they are helpful. Just evaluate both sides at $x=\pm i$, just as you did with $x=0$.

Comment: You might notice that $x^{20}+x^{18} = (x^3+x)x^{17}$.

Comment: @B.Goddard now I get you as I was getting stopped at 1 variable left. LostinSpace has explained how to deal with it. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, apparently many different approaches do the job.

Comment: @lulu you were right. It was indeed helpful here. It's just that generally in such questions the complex terms aren't helpful (neither I'm not good with them). But here, it wasn't hard either. But Prem's suggestion to use GP to compute was very helpful to ease calculation.

Comment: Well , of course PARI/GP can calculate such exercises immediately , but the point is to do it by hand.

Comment: The GP in Earlier Comment refers to Geometric Progression , @Peter

Comment: Downvotes without comment aren't appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to divide by $x^3+x = x(x^2+1)$, hence by the Chinese remainder theorem it is enough to check the remainders $\pmod{x}$ (which is obviously zero) and $\pmod{x^2+1}$. This remainder is simply given by setting $x^2\equiv -1$, such that
$$ x^{10}+x^{11}+\ldots+x^{19}+x^{20} \equiv (-1-x+1+x)+(-1-x+1+x)+(-1-x+1+x)\color{red}{-x} $$
and option $(B)$ is apparent now.

Comment: Oh! Such a straightforward and uncomplicated answer. Upvoted. It is such a solution when I say to myself, as said by Helen Keller: Those who do not see even by seeing. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Most useful for multiple choice is very quick elimination methods by considering special cases.

Put $x = 2$. The original expression is a geometric sum with number of terms, first term and common ratio being respectively $11,2^{20},2$ and it has the sum $2^{10}(2^{11} - 1) = (1024)(2047)$.

The divisor is $2^3 + 2 = 10$.

The original value modulo $10$ is $(4)(7) = 28 \equiv 8 \equiv -2 \pmod{10}$,so the only choice that fits is (B)$-x$.

By the way, using $x=1$ etc. doesn't help narrow down the possibilities sufficiently.

The above took me less than half a minute. It is a good technique for MCQ but (of course) not for open-ended questions.

Comment: (+1) for the creative solution (although it relies on that one of the options is correct)

Comment: Wow! Great! Thank you for taking into account the very purpose of me adding "contest-math" tag. Sometimes solving just by procedure is indeed very time draining. Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

The polynomial $x^{k+2}+x^k$ is divisible by $x^3+x$ for $k\ge 1.$ Hence $[x^{13}+x^{14}+\ldots +x^{20}]$ and $x^{10}+x^{12}$ are divisible by $x^3+x.$ We are down to $x^{11}$ (thanks @Cathedral ) and $$\displaylines{x^{11}=x^{11}+x^9-(x^9+x^7)+(x^7+x^5)\\ -(x^5+x^3)+(x^3+x)-x}$$
The remainder is equal $-x.$

Comment: $x^{11}+\cdots +x^{20}$ is not divisible by $x^3+x$

Comment: I think you mean that only $x^{11}$ is left over... which does in fact leave $-x$ as the remainder.

Comment: $-x$ is correct (see my answer)

Comment: Thanks. I will re-edit soon

Comment: @Cathedral You are absolutely right.

Comment: Thank you! Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

What about this : We have for example $$x^{10}+x^{12}=x^{10}(x^2+1)\equiv 0\mod x(x^2+1)$$

This way we can also cancel $11-13,14-16,15-17,18-20$. It remains $x^{19}$ for which you can use $x^6\equiv x^2$ giving $x^{18}\equiv x^6$ hence $x^{18}\equiv x^2$ hence $x^{19}\equiv x^3\equiv -x$ $\mod (x^3+x)$

Comment: Why $ x^6≡x^2$?

Comment: We have $x^3\equiv -x\mod (x^3+x)$ . Now just square both sides

Comment: 1. Why spoilers should not be in question? Is it not good to tell others that I know the answer? 2. (I know this is rookie thing but) I'm not aware with "mod" properties so I see $x^3≡−x$ but how it works I need to know.  Please enlighten me.

Comment: @InanimateBeing $p \equiv a \text{ mod } b$ means $(p-a)$ is divisible by $b$. Clearly, $x^3-(-x)$ is divisible by $x^3+x$.

Comment: Oh, alright. Now I see. Thanks a lot @Cathedral.

Comment: In this case, take the solution of Lost in Space. If you have congruences $a\equiv b\mod n$ and $c\equiv d\mod n$ , you can add and multiply both sides so we both have $a+c\equiv b+d\mod n$ and $ac\equiv bd\mod n$. This generalizes to more factors and higer powers (for example you can also cube both sides which I used in my answer)

Comment: @Peter great short answer. Upvoted. But the spoiler thing I still don't get.

Comment: The purpose of this site is that questions with context are answered by someone and not to challenge every user to try this for his/her own (although of course everyone really wanting to do that can do it).

Comment: Oh, I never mean to challenge anybody. If you suggest not providing answer when I know it despite being interested in only the procedure then I won't. But often when answerers find I knew the answer and didn't disclose that I know it, they get irked and consider that rude too. So basically I'm in a (great) paradox.

Comment: It is correct to share everything you know about the problem (also the final answer, if you happen to know it) , just mention it and do not hide it with a spoiler.

Comment: @Peter thanks a lot for your guidance :-)

Answer (score 5):

$\begin{align}p(x)&=x^{20}+x^{19}+\dots+x^{10}\\&=x^{17}(x^3+x)+x^{16}(x^3+x)+x^{13}(x^3+x)+x^{12}(x^3+x)+x^9(x^3+x)+\color{red}{x^{11}}\end{align}$

Again $x^{11}=x^8(x^3+x) -x^6(x^3+x) +x^4(x^3+x) -x^2(x^3+x) +(x^3+x) -x$

Hence remainder is $=-x$

Comment: Smooth! Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

$\overbrace{\!\!\bmod \color{c00}{x^2\!+\!1}}^{\color{#c00}{\large x^2\ \equiv\ -1}\!\!}\!:\ f\color{#0af}{\!+\!x^9} =\! (x^9\!+\!x^{13}\!+\!x^{17})\!\!\overbrace{(1\!+\!x\!+\!x^2\!+\!x^3)}^{\large  ((\color{#c00}{x^2})^2-1)/(x-1)=\color{#0a0}0}\!\!\equiv\color{#0a0}0\,$ so $\,f \equiv \color{#0af}{-x^9} = -x(\color{#c00}{x^2})^4\! \equiv -x$

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Here $x$ is common, hence we can "cancel" it to get $x^9+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+ \cdots +x^{19}$ & $x^2+1$

By your method, let this be $f(x) = (x^2+1)g(x)+ax+b$

At $x=i$, we get $x^9+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+ \cdots +x^{19} = 0 + ai+b$
At $x=-i$, we get $x^9+x^{10}+x^{11}+x^{12}+ \cdots +x^{19} = 0 - ai+b$

LHS in both can be calculated by Geometric Progression.
We will end up with $2$ Simultaneous Equations having complex co-efficients.

Solving that will give the required reminder.

Alternately, we know that $x^4 = 1$ when $x=i$ or $x=-i$.

With that, we can reduce the given Equations:
$x^1+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{0}+ \cdots +x^{3} = 0 + ai+b$
$x^1+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{0}+ \cdots +x^{3} = 0 - ai+b$

$(+i)+(-1)+(-i)+(+1)+ \cdots +(-i) = 0 + ai+b$
$(-i)+(-1)+(+i)+(+1)+ \cdots +(+i) = 0 - ai+b$

$(0i)+(-1) = 0 + ai+b$
$(0i)+(-1) = 0 - ai+b$

Both give $(a,b)=(0,-1)$

Plugging into the original, before we did the "cancellation", we get $0x^2-x = -x$

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

We want to find the remainder from the division:$$\frac{x^{20} + x^{19} + \ldots + x^{11} + x^{10}}{x^3 + x}$$

Now note that $$ (x^3 + x)(x^{n+1} + x^n ) = x^{n+4} + x^{n+3} + x^{n+2} + x^{n+1}, $$

so that

$$ \frac{x^{20} + x^{19} + \ldots + x^{11} + x^{10}}{x^3 + x} = x^{17} + x^{16} + x^{13} + x^{12} + \frac{x^{12} + x^{11} + x^{10}}{x^3 + x} $$

and using long division you can show that the remainder from the final term is  $-x.$

Peter's method is more efficient though.

Comment: Great answer! Nice way to cut down on the length. Upvoted. Also, now that I think about it, how about this: add and subtract $\bf x^9+x^8+\dots+x$ then make pairs of 4 to be finally left with $\bf -x$. Is this alright?